# Powershell - SelectXML XPath with parameter variable

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, parameters, gpo

Hello powershell fellows,

unfortunatly i have another issue and i dont know how to solve it with Select-XML and XPath. This time i'm not even sure if my requirement can be met at all. But maybe you have some great ideas again.

**Introduction**

I have a xml file (xml export of a AD GPO) and i try to fetch information out of this xml with select-xml. This process is depict in a function and i want to transfer the XPath value of select-xml from a parameter input. So far everything fine.
Let me quickly show you my code and my xml and afterwards i will explain my issue

*XML:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
-<GPO xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    -<Identifier>
        <Identifier xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types"></Identifier>
        <Domain xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">Testdomain.local</Domain>
    </Identifier>
    <Name>ExampleName</Name>
    <IncludeComments>true</IncludeComments>
    <CreatedTime>2022-07-26T11:12:25</CreatedTime>
    <ModifiedTime>2022-07-26T11:56:44</ModifiedTime>
    <ReadTime>2022-07-26T11:56:52.7975554Z</ReadTime>
    -<Computer>
        <VersionDirectory>1</VersionDirectory>
        <VersionSysvol>1</VersionSysvol>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        -<ExtensionData>
            -<Extension xsi:type="q1:SecuritySettings" xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security">
                -<q1:SecurityOptions>
                    <q1:KeyName>TestKeyName</q1:KeyName>
                    <q1:SettingNumber>5</q1:SettingNumber>
                    -<q1:Display>
                        <q1:Name>TestName</q1:Name>
                        <q1:Units/>
                        <q1:DisplayString>TestValue</q1:DisplayString>
                    </q1:Display>
                </q1:SecurityOptions>
                -<q1:SecurityOptions>
                    <q1:KeyName>TestKeyName2</q1:KeyName>
                    <q1:SettingNumber>5</q1:SettingNumber>
                    -<q1:Display>
                        <q1:Name>TestName2</q1:Name>
                        <q1:Units/>
                        <q1:DisplayString>TestValue2</q1:DisplayString>
                    </q1:Display>
                </q1:SecurityOptions>
         ...
```

*My Funtion*

```
function Test-XPath {

    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Policy_Identifier_XPath,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Policy_Identifier_Name,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Policy_Setting_Name_XPath,
    )

    $namespace = @{ns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings";xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security"}

    $keynames = (Select-Xml -Path "C:\testfolder\test.xml" -XPath $Policy_Identifier_XPath -Namespace $namespace).Node.InnerText ##This Select-XML with XPath as parameter is working totally fine.
    $index = [array]::IndexOf($keynames, $Policy_Identifier_Name) ##Selecte-XML gives back an array of results (See in the XML-> 2 results for KeyName). I uniquly identify the $Policy_Identifier_Name in the XML array, i am searching for.
    $index = $index +1
    $name_2 = (Select-Xml -Path "C:\testfolder\test.xml" -XPath $Policy_Setting_Name_XPath  -Namespace $namespace).Node.InnerText ##This Select-XML with XPath as paramter doesnt work. I assume it is because i need to use $index in this XPath call.

}

Test-XPath -Policy_Identifier_XPath "//q1:SecurityOptions/q1:KeyName" -Policy_Identifier_Name "TestKeyName" -Policy_Setting_Name_XPath '"//q1:SecurityOptions[$index]/q1:Display/q1:Name"'
```

**Problem**

The first time i call the Select-XML with the XPath value as a paramter everything is working fine. But the second call of Select-XML doesnt work. I assume it is because i refer to $index within the parameter. But i need $index within the second XPath value to uniquly identify the $Policy_Identifier_Name in the XML array. Also notice the comments in my code for better insight of the issue.
The Error powershell gives me back:
Select-Xml : Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

**What i tried so far**

I tried different types quotes at the paramter Policy_Setting_Name_XPath when calling the function Test-XPath. But none worked.

Maybe you fellows have some ideas with this issue.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see any `DisplayFields` in the input sample.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: You are right, thank you :)!  I edited the sample to be consistent. But the root of the problem stays the same ;). The provided xml is just a sample.

Comment: I am not well versed in the whole syntax of Powershell and its string and variables escaping and interpolation rules so I can't really judge whether the attempt of `"//q1:SecurityOptions/q1:KeyName"` vs `'"//q1:SecurityOptions[$index]/q1:Display/q1:Name"'` makes any sense. In terms of XPath, however, you just need a single path using one variable e.g. `$Policy_Identifier_XPath = "TestKeyName"` and then you can use e.g. `-xpath  "//q1:SecurityOptions[q1:KeyName = '$Policy_Identifier_XPath']/q1:Display/q1:Name"`

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried your solution and it works very well! I think i can change my script so your solution fits in.
I am relativly new to working with xpath, and this helped a lot ! Thank you

Comment: @MartinHonnen
One small addition to XPath syntax:
If i want to check wether Name and Value in my XPath is equivalent to a certain value. How do i perform this?

"//q1:SecurityOptions[q1:KeyName = '$Policy_Identifier_Name']/q1:Display[[/q1:Name='TestName'] and [/q1:DisplayString='TestValue']]"

Comment: It would be `//q1:SecurityOptions[q1:KeyName = '$Policy_Identifier_Name']/q1:Display[q1:Name='TestName' and q1:DisplayString='TestValue']`, if I read your sample and your intention correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think slow and steady I'm getting the hang of it with XPath.